# How to get info from an object created from json

Tags: json, vba

I have a json string:  `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"event":{"id":"27151641","name":"TSW Pegasus FC (Res) v Sun Hei SC (Res)","countryCode":"HK","timezone":"GMT","openDate":"2014-02-19T12:30:00.000Z"},"marketCount":14},{"event":{"id ":"27151646","name":"Humble Lions v Boys Town FC...` etc etc

So the result bit is a list of event/marketcount pairs.  I've used the parse method in a class module called jsonlib which I got from http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/issues/attachmentText?id=15&aid=150001000&name=jsonlib.cls&token=31ObtlGBtaGXd2KR0QLyffX_x8Y:1359742317106

This creates an object (jason_obj) which represents the result bit above. Now I want to get a list of ids for each event. I can use the for each ... construct to return each event/marketcount pair as an object, but I can't work out how to get to the id field that is somewhere in the event object. I tried to use the tostring method to get a clue, and from that this code should work but it doesn't:

```
For Each eventItem In jason_obj
 this_eventx = eventItem("event")
 this_id = this_eventx("id")
 Next
```

Don't know much about accessing objects/collections. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Objects need to be set and references should use item:

For Each eventItem In jason_obj

set this_eventx = eventItem.item("event")

this_id = this_eventx.item("id")

Next

HTH

Yes it did